# How to compile .jrxml only once

Tags: java, jasper-reports

Please Help:
.jrxml is compiling every time i generate the report. I want to compile it only once. please help me what condition should i need to add. i am not using input/output stream. with compileReport what can be done to compile only once.

Answer (score 3):

Don't make your JRXML file available anywhere that is web accessible. The JRXML file contains easily read SQL statements, which give away:

- Database vendor
- Database structure

Malicious users can use this information for nefarious purposes. I tend to move the SQL statements into database views or stored procedures, which hides much information.

Your reports creation process should be as follows:

1. Talk with a Business Analyst to determine report requirements for all reports.
2. Amalgamate all reports that are simple variations (e.g., different column or sort order).
3. Create JRXML files for each report (one JRXML file can handle several report variations), store the JRXML file in a source code repository.
4. Compile the JRXML files to get `.jasper` files.
5. Store the compiled `.jasper` files in the repository and on the web server.
6. Remove the compilation step from your source code altogether.

In short, compiling the report is a process that you should do outside of the application environment. This is a step that the developer should take. The developer checks the compiled report into the repository and the test/build environment can fetch the latest copy.

Unless you have an absolute requirement to compile reports on-the-fly. Note that compiling reports on-the-fly does not really make sense unless you are creating dynamic reports. In that case, you'd want to use something like [DynamicJasper](http://dynamicjasper.com/).

All that said, the answer to your question is this:

1. Try to obtain the source for `Sample_Report.jasper`.
2. If the `Sample_Report.jasper` resource does not exist, then compile as you've shown.
3. If the resource does exist, avoid the compilation step.

This might resemble:

```
JasperReport jasReport = null;

try {
  jasReport = (JasperReport)JRLoader.loadObject(
    getResourceAsStream("Sample_Report.jasper")
  );
}
catch( Exception e ) {
  jasperReport = JasperCompileManager.compileReport(
    getResourceAsStream("Sample_Report.jrxml")
  );
}
```

You will have to ensure the correct directories and the files can be loaded if they do, in fact, exist in those locations. You will also have to save the compiled report after it has been compiled, so that the next iteration will pick up the `.jasper` file.

To save the compiled `.jasper` file, you can use the following [API](http://jasperreports.sourceforge.net/api/index.html):

```
JasperCompileManager.compileReportToStrem(input, output);
```

See also:

- http://community.jaspersoft.com/questions/527132/how-load-jasper-instead-jrxml
- http://community.jaspersoft.com/questions/538416/how-save-compiled-jasper-object-database-blob