# Is it better to use .jasper or .jrxml in web application?

Tags: performance, jasper-reports, report, reporting

I have been working with jasper reports for quite some time
All these days, I have compiled `.jrxml` files using `IReport` tool and copied the `.jasper` file in  
 my web application. I know of the `JaperCompileManager` which does compiling of `.jrxml` and produce `.jasper` files at the run time. Have few queries about it

1. Will it compile and produce `.jasper` file each time I open the report or compile and preserve the .jasper file till any change happens in `.jrxml` file?
2. Is there any performance impact in doing this run time compilation
3. Which approach is better? Using pre compiled jasper files or use `.jrxmls` for run time compilation?

Comment: If your templates are immutable it is better to use *jasper* files. You can write simple test for calculating the time of compilation

Comment: Thats right Alex. I can put some simple calculation for the time. Just wanted to know what is the normal practice around

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Jasper files, are jrxml files compiled into Java bytecode, JasperReports requires the use of Jasper files so you need to compile your jrxml files for it to work, the compilation step is pretty costly, but it can be done once if you have the file cached somewhere and use something like what's defined here: [How to compile .jrxml only once](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14738332/how-to-compile-jrxml-only-once); however, if your reports are inmutable, then you're better compiling your reports before deploying them, both for performance and security purposes.

By the way, the official way of deploying Jasper reports is just deploy the jasper file.